# How to locally analyse ACRA crash report

Tags: android, mongodb, analysis, acra

Using [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-Implementing_your_own_sender) for a few days now and sending reports to my MongoDb backend HTTPS server, is there some tool I can use on my PC to analyse crash data.

I was thinking I could handle this locally and not use any of the Bugsense, Zubhium, HockeyApp, Google Docs.
I know the question is a bit fishy but I cannot find info about this since the general way seems to suggest the above Bugsense, Zub.

I know I get a richer and better overview of the crash data by using the above.

**Update** I tried the Google Docs to see how it works and ended up Implementing my own [sender](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-Implementing_your_own_sender), sending to my HTTPS server. For now the crash log is just save to a MongoDb `Document`

**Update**
I have an app on the google play market and it's using ACRA. The App have the custom ACRA `ReportSender` and it sends reports data back to my HTTPS server. I wanted to take care of this myself since the app already uses Internet

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to send crash reports to a local server in a development environment? It is heaps easier and you will much more detailed info just using the logcat output directly via adb.

Comment: This is an ACRA specific question. Read up on ACRA and you'll understand the question betten.

Comment: Erik, I'm one of the ACRA committers. I think I understand the question just fine.

Comment: some clarification, I'm new to acra..I have an app on the google play market and it's using ACRA. The App have the custom ACRA `ReportSender` and it sends reports data back to my HTTPS server. I wanted to take care of this myself since the app already uses Internet

Comment: OK so you want to locally analyze crash data that has been collected by your custom ACRA server from deployed applications? How you do that will depend entirely on what format your custom ACRA server is able to server up the data to you. I would suggest the simplest would be to use a spreadsheet to filter and sort them. This is one of the reasons that most of us use one of the commercial servers because they do that for you.

Comment: Yea that is my conclusion so fare. I figure if anyone knew it would be you, if there is a PC spreadsheet filtering program like the Bugsense e.g. I guess on of the problem with creation of the program is the lack of standardization for crash data